# I keep getting this error in Xcode when I build Designables, xcode (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')),

Tags: ios, apple-m1, xcode13

I have enabled Standard Architecture (arm64, armv7) and I tried removing arm64 from excluded architecture still getting the error.

I have a M1 chip mac book pro

Comment: Have you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: no still having the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285424/xcode-12-apple-m1-arm64-designable-error-wrong-architecture